# How do I call a method that is a hash value?

Tags: ruby, hash, methods, call

Previously, I asked about a clever way to execute a method on a given condition "[Ruby a clever way to execute a function on a condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061177/ruby-a-clever-way-to-execute-a-function-on-a-condition)."

The solutions and response time was great, though, upon implementation, having a hash of lambdas gets ugly quite quickly. So I started experimenting.

The following code works:

```
def a()
  puts "hello world"
end

some_hash = { 0 => a() }

some_hash[0]
```

But if I wrap this in a class it stops working:

```
class A

  @a = { 0 => a()}

  def a()
    puts "hello world"
  end


  def b()
    @a[0]
  end

end

d = A.new()

d.b()
```

I can't see why it should stop working, can anyone suggest how to make it work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

that code doesn't work.  it executes `a` at the time it is added to the hash, not when it is retrieved from the hash (try it in irb).

It doesn't work in the class because there is no `a` method defined on the class (you eventually define a method `a` on the instance.

Try actually using lambdas like

```
{0 => lambda { puts "hello world" }}
```

instead

Comment: That's really what I was trying to avoid. The code I would put in the lambda can get a bit messy, and I'll have about 15 elements in the hash. It clutters up the code a bit.

Comment: @Peter: Is the code messier in a lambda than it would be in a method?

Comment: then pass the method names as symbols and use send or Symbol#to_proc.

Comment: @Chuck it would be identical, but wrapping the code in methods then referencing them in the hash seems a more beautiful solution.

Comment: have you considered creating a class method that could take a block and add it as a lambda to your hash and then just use it as needed in your class body.

Comment: I'm not sure what that even means, sorry! Using send as you suggested seems ideal, however.

Comment: basically, you could create a method like `self.add_condition(a, &b)` on your class that simply adds the block b to a class level hash.  Then you can retrieve and call the block as a method.  In your class body you would have `add_condition 0 { puts "hello world" }` or something

Comment: Here's an example of what Ben is talking about (add it in A): def self.condition(cond, &block) @conditions ||= {}; @conditions[cond] = block; end

Answer (score 5):

First of all, you are not putting a lambda in the hash. You're putting the result of calling `a()` in the current context.

Given this information, consider what the code in your class means. The context of a class definition is the class. So you define an instance method called `a`, and assign a class instance variable to the a hash containing the result of calling `a` in the current context. The current context is the class A, and class A does not have a class method called `a`, so you're trying to put the result of a nonexistent method there. Then in the instance method `b`, you try to access an instance variable called `@a` -- but there isn't one. The `@a` defined in the class context belongs to the class itself, not any particular instance.

So first of all, if you want a lambda, you need to make a lambda. Second, you need to be clear about the difference between a class and an instance of that class.

If you want to make a list of method names to be called on certain conditions, you can do it like this:

```
class A
  def self.conditions() { 0 => :a } end

  def a
    puts "Hello!"
  end

  def b(arg)
    send self.class.conditions[arg]
  end
end
```

This defines the conditions hash as a method of the class (making it easy to access), and the hash merely contains the name of the method to call rather than a lambda or anything like that. So when you call `b(0)`, it `send`s itself the message contained in A.conditions[0], which is `a`.

Answer (score 3):

If you really just want to pretty this sort of thing up,
why not wrap all your methods in a class like so:

```
# a container to store all your methods you want to use a hash to access
class MethodHash
  alias [] send
  def one
    puts "I'm one"
  end
  def two
    puts "I'm two"
  end
end

x = MethodHash.new
x[:one] # prints "I'm one"
x.two # prints "I'm one"
```

or, to use your example:

```
# a general purpose object that transforms a hash into calls on methods of some given object
class DelegateHash
  def initialize(target, method_hash)
    @target = target
    @method_hash = method_hash.dup
  end
  def [](k)
    @target.send(@method_hash[k])
  end
end

class A
  def initialize
    @a = DelegateHash.new(self, { 0 => :a })
  end
  def a()
    puts "hello world"
  end
  def b()
    @a[0]
  end
end

x = A.new
x.a #=> prints "hello world"
x.b #=> prints "hello world"
```

One other basic error that you made is that you initialized `@a` outside of any instance method -
just bare inside of the definition of `A`.  This is a big time no-no, because it just doesn't work.
Remember, in ruby, everything is an object, including classes, and the `@` prefix means the instance
variable of whatever object is currently self.  Inside an instance method definitions, `self` is an instance
of the class.  But outside of that, just inside the class definition, `self` is the class object - so you defined
an instance variable named `@a` for the class object `A`, which none of the instances of `A` can get to directly.

Ruby does have a reason for this behaviour (class instance variables can be really handy if you know what
you're doing), but this is a more advanced technique.

In short, only initialize instance variables in the `initialize` method.

Answer (score 3):

```
table = {
  :a => 'test',
  :b => 12,
  :c => lambda { "Hallo" },
  :d => def print(); "Hallo in test"; end
}

puts table[:a]
puts table[:b]
puts table[:c].call
puts table[:d].send( :print )
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, the first line in your class calls a method that doesn't exist yet. It won't even exist after the whole class is loaded though, since that would be a call to the class method and you've only defined instance methods.

Also keep in mind that {0 => a()} will call the method a(), not create a reference to the method a(). If you wanted to put a function in there that doesn't get evaluated until later, you'd have to use some kind of Lambda.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realise that. Well, is there anyway to achieve what I was trying to do?

Comment: You could do something like this:

@a = {0 => lambda{A.new.a()}}

Then you would have to call it with @a[0].call

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty new to using callbacks in Ruby and this is how I explained it to myself using an example:

```
require 'logger'
log = Logger.new('/var/tmp/log.out')

def callit(severity, msg, myproc)
  myproc.call(sev, msg)
end

lookup_severity = {}
lookup_severity['info'] = Proc.new { |x| log.info(x) }
lookup_severity['debug'] = Proc.new { |x| log.debug(x) }

logit = Proc.new { |x,y| lookup_sev[x].call(y) }

callit('info', "check4", logit)
callit('debug', "check5", logit)
```

Answer (score 0):

> a = ->(string="No string passed") do
>
> puts string
>
> end
>
> some_hash = {   0 => a }
>
> some_hash[0].call("Hello World")
>
> some_hash[0][]