# Refactoring repetitive case statements in Ruby

Tags: ruby, refactoring

Is there a better way to shorten these repetitive switch case statements? Perhaps, an even more readable solution?

```
isTyping = true
accMenu = ['Balance', 'Withdraw', 'Deposit', 'Exit']
account = Account.new('Jason Bourne', 278430, 100.0)
while isTyping do
  accMenu.each_with_index { |str, i| print i+1, '. ', str, "\n" }
  print 'Enter account option: '
  accOption = gets.to_i
  case accOption                                                                                                                                                         
  when 1
    puts "Account Balance: #{account.balance}"
  when 2
    puts 'How much to withdraw from account? '
    debit = gets.to_f
    account.withdraw(debit)
  when 3
    puts 'How much to deposit from account? '
    credit = gets.to_f
    account.deposit(credit)
  when 4
    isTyping = false
  else
    puts 'Invalid account option, try again!'
  end
end
```

Comment: Repetitive case statements? What is repeated?

Comment: When, when, when... I don't have a problem with this setup, but if there's something more elegant It wouldn't hurt to know.

Comment: check this then http://stackoverflow.com/a/1071622/1004274

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
accMenu = %w[Balance Withdraw Deposit Exit]
account = Account.new("Jason Bourne", 278430, 100.0)
loop do
  accMenu.each.with_index(1){|str, i| puts "#{i}. #{str}"}
  print "Enter account option: "
  case gets.to_i
  when 1
    puts "Account Balance: #{account.balance}"
  when 2
    puts "How much to withdraw from account?"
    account.withdraw(gets.to_f)
  when 3
    puts "How much to deposit from account?"
    account.deposit(gets.to_f)
  when 4
    break
  else
    puts "Invalid account option, try again!"
  end
end
```

It is not good to use magic numbers. You may want to make your code more readable by doing this:

```
  case accMenu[gets.to_i]
  when "Balance"
    puts "Account Balance: #{account.balance}"
  when "Withdraw"
    puts "How much to withdraw from account?"
    account.withdraw(gets.to_f)
  when "Deposit"
    puts "How much to deposit from account?"
    account.deposit(gets.to_f)
  when "Exit"
    break
  else
    puts "Invalid account option, try again!"
  end
```

But you may prefer the first one, I don't know.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know you could seed .each with a start value of like that. I hope you don't mind me asking, what's the %w?

Comment: It is a way to write an array literal. Search for %-notation in Ruby.

Comment: I definitely will, I appreciate the help.

Comment: Both of them are clear, but what do you mean by magic numbers?

Comment: Magic numbers are numbers that are used in code that do not have inherent meaning. It is an established terminology in computing. In the old days, or in low level programming, code was/is full of magic numbers. Nowadays, it is generally agreed that you should avoid them.

Comment: I see.. I have a Java background and I had never learned about that other than hearing about magic strings within PHP. I learn something new every time I get on here.

Answer (score 0):

yeah, make a hash with a lambda to call and do the lookup into the hash and then call the code block.

http://www.robertsosinski.com/2008/12/21/understanding-ruby-blocks-procs-and-lambdas/

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Comment: just started a LoL game.  I'll check this when it's over.  but basically hash[1]=Lambda.new(...)

Comment: I'll take a look into. Thanks for the link as well.

Comment: then when you get the input, use that to look it up in the hash and call the associated lambda

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16699595/how-to-use-truly-local-variables-in-ruby-proc-lambda